# Snubber circuit for TRIAC

Tags: c, triac, snubber

I have built TRIAC circuit below which I got off the internet. Without the snubber circuit works good, but with snubber the TRIAC is always on. I'm using 9v ac just for testing purposes. Can someone explain why snubber makes it so TRIAC is always on?

[image]

Comment: http://www.elec.canterbury.ac.nz/intranet/dsl/p90-links/doc-include/power_electronics/snubber_circuits_and_triacs.pdf I guess this will help

Comment: R2 is too big for 9VAC. May be opto is not closing?

Comment: What is the load?  CX1 will have an impedance - maybe this is what you're observing?

Comment: @user263983 how big should R2 be?

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios Did you want to ask "how small"? Opening voltage divide by minimum gate current. Good luck.